# Differentiating debug and production build of an Android app

Tags: java, android, debugging, maven

I recently started learning about Android app development. It's also my first experience with the Java language.

There are some debugging tools that I want to incorporate into my app development in a form of Java package dependency. For obvious reasons, I would like to include it only for debug builds.

In iOS, we can use build configuration to link with debugging libraries only for debug builds, and use macros to remove parts of code that deals with debugging. This makes it really easy to switch between debug and production builds. Anyway to achieve the same for Android?

So far, the closest I got is using Maven profiles to overwrite properties files, which gets loaded by the application, but this requires that the debugging libraries are still imported.

---

To clarify my question, here is what I want to do:
I built a library that will let you browse the SQLite database on your browser. It's really useful for debugging purposes, but I don't want to ship my app with the library.

Another purpose is to use HockeyApp. HockeyApp provides two features: Update notification, and crash reporting. I need three different builds for this to work:

- Production: Crash reporting On, Update notification Off
- Beta: Both On
- Debug: Both Off

Answer (score 4):

In the manifest's [`<application>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), you can set the `debuggable` attribute. Eclipse does this for you automatically if you omit the attribute. Debug builds have `debuggable=true`, well exported builds have `debuggable=false`.

This affects Log.d, and you can conditionally check in code using the following:

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Maven, one way is to use a dependency injector like [Dagger](http://square.github.com/dagger/)

> By building on standard javax.inject annotations (JSR-330), each class is easy to test. You don't need a bunch of boilerplate just to swap the RpcCreditCardService out for a FakeCreditCardService.
>
> Dependency injection isn't just for testing. It also makes it easy to create reusable, interchangeable modules. You can share the same AuthenticationModule across all of your apps. And you can run DevLoggingModule during development and ProdLoggingModule in production to get the right behavior in each situation.

Comment: That's useful for testing, but I'm asking about the actual app. I want to have developer builds, QA testing builds, and production builds.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's essentially a code generator. With it, you can generate a build for developers, one for debugging, one for QA, one for production, etc.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk how exactly?  It generates code for dependency injection but I don't see how you can tell it to use different dependencies in different build environments.  Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @DavidCowden and Barum Rho, I'm sorry. I'm afraid I spoke too quickly. I just learned about this library last week and I was relying only on what was my first impression of the library. I need to get my head around it before I can create a good example for it. Hopefully, I'll be able to create such an example. The made-up CoffeeMaker example they have on there does not seem that helpful actually.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yeah I think this looks really interesting too and I think there is a way to do what the OP wants with it.  I just don't see it right away and was wondering if you had any more insight.  Please let me know if you come up with a good example -- I'll be pondering it as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to check the return value of [PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). It returns null if the apk was installed manually through adb, through a web page, or through a service like HockeyApp. In fact, I recently added a similar check to our sdk, see [this commit](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android/commit/a18774c97af53405c48956d548aa6f26be930821).

Note that this solution is only reliable if you only distribute your (paid) app though Google Play. Last time I checked, alternative stores like the Amazon App Store or AndroidPIT were not setting the installer source (it is possible to set it since API level 11, see [PackageManager#setInstallerPackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setInstallerPackageName)).

Another option is to check the package name at runtime. For your beta builds, you would append ".beta" to the package name and then check for this suffix to enable in-app updates or debug stuff. You can do this by moving your code base into a library project and set up two app projects that reference this library project: one for the store app, one for the beta app. Our use aapt with the option `--rename-manifest-package` to change the package name of beta builds (see details [here](http://www.piwai.info/renaming-android-manifest-package/)).

Answer (score 0):

do you have use BuildConfig.DEBUG, this is created by android adt tool

/gen/BuildConfig

Comment: This is probably the closest answer. I just wish it had more flexibility.

Comment: Another person mentioned proguard, which strips out unused classes. The combination of `BuildConfig` and proguard may strip out debug only classes, but I don't like the uncertainty.