# Changing a value for debug and production in java/android

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have a java statement like this:

```
int MAX_CACHE_AGE = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(14);
```

And I want to have a max cache age of 0 when debugging. However, I also want to minimize the complexity of my build. What are some ways I can do this? How do you do this? I am developing for Android so if your method is Android specific, tell my anyway.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022653/how-to-check-programmatically-whether-app-is-running-in-debug-mode-or-not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696361/differentiating-debug-and-production-build-of-an-android-app/

Comment: Those answers would be nice, but getApplicationInfo().flags is always 0 for me.

Comment: Those answers don't work for me: getApplicationInfo().flags is always 0. Even with android:debuggable in the application part of my AndroidManifest. Also, they require a context to be available, which is not true everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize this variable in the onCreate() method if it's in an application component, or in the constructor if it's in a normal Java class. The Android tools have a BuildConfig class that is auto generated. You can use its DEBUG field to alter the value.

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    MAX_CACHE_AGE = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(0);
} else {
    MAX_CACHE_AGE = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(14);
}
```